# Understanding Java Predicates

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

I have a problem understanding Java Predicates...

Example:

```
public class UserPredicates {
 public static Predicate<User> isNameEmpty() {
  return p -> p.getFirstName().isEmpty() && p.getLastName().isEmpty();
 }
}
```

The above example confusing to me, how does it know that `p` have the method `getFirstName()` and `getLastName()`?
If I understand it correctly, `isNameEmpty()` returns a function with one parameter (`p`), but does the compiler really figure out the type by looking at the return type?

And the returned function is `test()` from the Predicate interface?

Comment: *does the compiler really figure out the type by looking at the return type?* That's exactly right. If you want to be explicit, you can do `(User p) -> ...`.

Answer (score 2):

`Predicate<User>` means a function that takes a `User` as its parameter, and returns a `boolean`.

See [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

> Interface Predicate
>   ...
>      Type Parameters:
>          T - the type of the input to the predicate